# Problem with post-hoc emmeans() test after lmerTest

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

I have a dataset looking at a response variable (Fat %), over time (Week 0-4), and over a treatment condition -- short vs long day.
I used a lmer model test to find out if the variables and interaction term were significant and it was significant. I want to look further at the interaction term (so basically a Tukey test but still accounting for the repeated measures). That's when I started to use the emmeans package and the output is not giving me the full output I would like. Any suggestions I would love, thank you.

here is my data set:

```
structure(list(`Bird ID` = c(61, 62, 71, 72, 73, 76, 77, 63, 
64, 69), Day = c("long", "long", "long", "long", "long", "long", 
"long", "short", "short", "short"), Week = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `Body Weight` = c(34.57, 41.05, 37.74, 37.04, 33.38, 
35.6, 31.88, 34.32, 35.5, 35.78), `Fat %` = c(2.42718446601942, 
2.07515423443634, 11.7329093799682, 8.61137591356848, 5.36031238906638, 
7.9879679144385, 1.2263099219621, 5.17970401691332, 8.73096446700508, 
3.62993896562801), `Lean %` = c(97.5728155339806, 97.9248457655636, 
88.2670906200318, 91.3886240864315, 94.6396876109336, 92.0120320855615, 
98.7736900780379, 94.8202959830867, 91.2690355329949, 96.370061034372
), `Fat(g)` = c(0.7, 0.74, 3.69, 2.71, 1.51, 2.39, 0.33, 1.47, 
2.58, 1.13), `Lean(g)` = c(28.14, 34.92, 27.76, 28.76, 26.66, 
27.53, 26.58, 26.91, 26.97, 30), ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

code I have tried:
model:

```
model3b <- lmer( `Fat %` ~ Day + Week + Day:Week +  (1|ID), data=jussara_data)
summary(model3b)
```

```
resp <- jussara_data$`Fat %`
f1 <- jussara_data$Week
f2 <- jussara_data$Day
```

```
fit1 = lm(log(resp) ~ f1 + f2 + f1:f2, data = jussara_data)
emm1 = emmeans(fit1, specs = pairwise ~ f1:f2)
emm1$emmeans
emm1$contrasts
```

The contrasts function I was hoping it would give me the summary looking something like this (but I need the repeated measures included not just this anova analysis):

```
Fat % groups
4:short 32.065752      a
3:short 27.678036      a
2:short 21.358485      b
4:long  13.895404      c
1:short 13.138941      c
2:long  12.245741      c
3:long  12.138498      c
1:long  10.315978     cd
0:short  6.134327      d
0:long   5.631602      d
```

but instead only gave me this:

```
f1 f2    emmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  2 long    2.24 0.0783 66     2.09     2.40
  2 short   2.80 0.0783 66     2.64     2.95

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
 contrast         estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 2 long - 2 short   -0.556 0.111 66 -5.025  <.0001 

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have Week as a numeric predictor. Thus you get the average of the Week values. Also the model is probably wrong because it assumes there is a linear effect of Week. Re-do the analysis after replacingWeek with factor(Week).

Comment: Second, I am really put off by your obfuscating your analysis by replacing perfectly good factor names Day and Week by abstractions f1 and f2. Are you trying to make it harder to understand what you're talking about? Because that's what you're accomplishing.